# What brand is this (maybe Eastern) frame? Is it good for a first bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

What brand is this frame? I think it may be Eastern but I'm not sure. Also is it good for a first bike?

[image]

Comment: It's a bike.  I see a similar one every week or two in my "job" rehabbing donated bikes for charity.  The usual problem encountered is that the brake cables are rusted up -- the front cable in particular seems designed to collect rainwater and rust (though the rear cable arrangement is sufficiently complicated to have several failure modes).

Comment: BTW, it would be a lousy first bike.  It's designed for trick riding, and is too small for an adult and not particularly stable as a first bike for a child.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the frame it looks to be a flatland styled BMX. The actual model or brand is hard to say, can you provide any additional pictures of what the decals say or the head badge?

***Assuming that you are an average sized adult that is not planning to take up flatland or BMX riding it would not be ideal.*** You would be best suited finding something that will be more comfortable over an extended amount of time and fit your body a little better. It will save your knees and back.

*If you are going to be trying your hand at BMX* then sure give it a whirl. It appears to have a gyro (meaning you can spin the bars all the way around without tangling cables) And a sturdy BMX 3 piece crank. The only kicker is that if it is an department store bike aka a BSO, then it was probably intended for a young person and not designed to take the weight of an adult beating on it, so you may want to invest in one that is made for an adult.

A bike is a bike, if you end up loving it and breaking the bike, that tells you that it would be worth getting a little more serious with your next purchase.

EDIT: here is the bicycle blue book on that bike, looks to be a 2010 Eastern Shock. [Bicycle Blue Book](http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/searchlistingdetail.aspx?id=3036395)

Notice the excellent price is about 100 bucks, if it's not pristine i would shoot for less.

Comment: Im not an adult im 14 would you think maybe i would fit it?

Comment: also it has decals that say "shock" on the frame and eastern bikes on the handles

Comment: If you are only 14 that should work for you just fine. I would be willing to guess it is an Eastern Shock, which is an entry level flatland bmx, not sure on the model year, the 2013 ones i found images of had a different downtube, the lower tube that connects to the crank. So it may be older than that. it was a 300 dollar bike brand new.

I have editted my answer to include a link to the blue book value of the bike to help you decide if it's right for you.